# Using cv.matchTemplate to find multiple best matches

Tags: opencv, template-matching

I am using the function `cv.matchTemplate` to try to find template matches.

`result = cv.matchTemplate(img, templ, match_method)`

After I run the function I have a bunch of answers in list `result`. I want to filter the list to find the best *n* matches. The data in `result` just a large array of numbers so I don't know what criteria to filter based on. Using `extremes = cv.minMaxLoc(result, None)` filters the result list in an undesired way before converting them to locations.

The match_method is `cv.TM_SQDIFF`. I want to:

- filter the results down to the best matches
- Use the results to obtain the locations

How can I acheive this?

Comment: [This tutorial](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html#template-matching) should get you started. Read at the bottom of the page for finding multiple matches.

Comment: This is helpful! thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treshold the result of matchTemplate to find locations with sufficient match. [This tutorial](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html) should get you started. Read at the bottom of the page for finding multiple matches.

```py
import numpy as np

threshold = 0.2
loc = np.where( result <= threshold) # filter the results
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]): #pt marks the location of the match
    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)
```

Keep in mind depending on the function you use will determine how you filter. `cv.TM_SQDIFF` tends to zero as the match quality increases so setting the `threshold` closer to zero filters out worse. The opposite is true for `cv.TM CCORR` `cv.TM_CCORR_NORMED` `cv.TM_COEFF` and `cv.TM_COEFF_NORMED` matching methods (better tends to 1)

Answer (score 4):

The above answer does not find the best N matches as the question asked. It filters out answers based on a threshold leaving open the (likely) possibility that you still have more than N results or zero results that beat the threshold.

To find the N 'best matches' we're looking for the N highest numbers in a 2d array and retrieving their indexes so we know the location. We can use [nump.argpartition](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) to find the highest N indexes in a 1d array and [numpy.ndarray.flatten](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) with [numpy.unravel_index](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) to go back and forth between a 2d and 1d array like so:

```
find_num = 5
result   = cv.matchTemplate(img, templ, match_method)
idx_1d   = np.argpartition(result.flatten(), -find_num)[-find_num:]
idx_2d   = np.unravel_index(idx_1d, result.shape)
```

From here you have the x,y locations of the top 5 matches.